# dotnet map default parameter values when using route attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I have a base class for my CMS controllers which has the route attribute:

```
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
```

I need this because we're using the `[HttpGet("{name}")` at different places.
In startup I defined a default including the `{area}`

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { area = "Start", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

But this is ignored because I override my route with the `[Route]` and `[HttpGet]` attributes. How do I set defaults for my route?

Previously I used a permanent redirect from the `/` URL to the home controller but because I'm using blazor with SignalR this is no longer possible because of routing issues with blazor server.

---

Is there any way to set the defaults in a `[Route]` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. Please correct me if it is. There is a workaround for people in a similar situation. Which is not my favourite but it works.

So attach `[Route("/")]` attribute to whatever action should be the default. Now directing to `foobar.com/` will open your "default" action. I'd preferred to define this globally instead of setting it on the action.